# Angular 4 weird error: query doesn't end when -not- showing a message toast

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Here this is, my weirdest error in my whole programming career. I've been struggling through this, yet I can't find what's going on in this code. It just seems not to make any sense in any way.

I'm using the following tools:

- Ionic 3
- Angular 4
- Typescript / ES6

I'm trying to do a method, "assignChat(user)", which assigns a chat to a user. It has to use several APIs, geolocation... it's a big method, actually. That's why I've split it in two parts connected by promises, and used them after, so my method looks pretty much like this:

```
    assignChat(user){
  const getLocationName = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      // 30 lines of code
    });
  }
  const assignOrCreateChat= (area) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      // 40 lines of code
    });
  }
  const getLocationName = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      // 30 lines of code
    });
  }


   // then I use the inner functions here and write an extra 60-70 lines of code  
}
```

Ok! This works neat. Didn't have much problems with this algorithm after some several testing, although is quite heavy and takes ~0.5s to properly execute, finish it's queries, and show the result.

Thing is... I had some toasts displaying some information, like where you're located. I wanted to remove them, and started by this one, in the inner function getLocationName(). This is the code I want to talk you about:

```
const getLocationName = () => {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            const ADDRESS_LEVEL = 2; 
            this.reverseGeocode(ADDRESS_LEVEL).then( address => {
      --->      this.toastify("You have been located at: "+address, 1500);
                let query = new Parse.Query("PoliticalArea");
                // more code
```

The line I marked with an arrow, is the line which is giving me problems. **I mean, you probably think the code fails because of the line, but it's totally the oposite! If I remove that line, the algorithm suddenly stops working and fails to display any result**.

The "toastify" method is a quick way I did for myself for displaying toasts. It works well, actually! This is the implementation:

```
   toastify(message, duration){       
      this.toastCtrl.create({
             message: message,
             duration: duration
      }).present();
   }
```

Not like the most dangerous method. Well, in fact, it seems that the code won't work without it. If I comment the line, or erase it, I never get any result, or any error, from the big algorithm I showed you before. I've got every possible exception catched, although the API connectors don't have timeout, but it's like it gets stuck every time it doesn't display the toast.

I just don't understand what's going on. Seems like a very serious thing the Angular team should look into, in my very honest opinion.

Any idea of what kind of black magic is going there?

UPDATE:

Some further info: when I navigate through the "bugged" view (without the toastify line, and therefore not displaying the chat result), and per example, click in another chat (which pushes a view into the Navigation Controller), it somehow starts showing the chat result I expected. When I pop the new view from the navCtrl, and get back to the page, the expected result is now visible.

Is this some problem with angular watches?

Comment: Its hard to tell exactly because not all the code is included (understandably), What i have experienced with the toasters is that they seem to work better ( i would get remote view not found errors ) if the `present()` is declared by a variable holding the `create({})` so `let toast = ...` and then `toast.present()` and maybe because it is a provider, with a `return` .. Also which lifecycle event is holding this code?

Comment: @arkade I somehow found an explanation: it didn't matter if I put this code in the constructor on in the ionViewDidEnter(), so I thought that maybe the view is trying to be rendered by Angular before it actually completes the task. I'm posting the fix in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution was not obvious.

It seems that the view was being rendered before the task completed. It was a tough task, so maybe that's the reason why Angular didn't work properly. Tried executing it both in the constructor and in ionViewDidEnter(), though nothing worked.

My final solution was to force component's re-rendering, through ApplicationRef, using the .tick() method at the dead end of my method.

That fixed it all!